# What is a correct way to paginate ignite cache?

Tags: java, pagination, ignite

I use apache ignite cache as data storage. Would like to know if there is a way to paginate a large data collection from the client. I do not need or want millions of records transfer from server to my web/mobile client.

```
private final ClientCache<UUID, Account> accounts;

public List<Account> getAll(int offset, int limit) 
{
    return accounts.query(new ScanQuery<UUID, Account>()
            .setLocal(false))
            .getAll()
            .stream()
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .map(entity -> entity.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is this an efficient way?

I looked at using a Cursor but the API is limited to iterator...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I see a `getAll()` in your code. It makes all data be transferred to the caller side. This exactly what you wanted to avoid.

`Iterator` avoids this problem, because data is loaded in batches on demand. So, you don't have to load everything into memory of a single node, when you run the query. Page size may be configured by setting [ScanQuery#pageSize](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/ScanQuery.html#setPageSize-int-) property. By default it's equal to 1024. Iterator may be acquired by calling `QueryCursor.iterator()` method. So, instead of keeping the offset, you need to keep an iterator.

SQL [SELECT](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/select) query with LIMIT and OFFSET specified is also an option. But in case if you have more than one node, then LIMIT + OFFSET records will be loaded from each node to the reducer during the execution. You should take it into account.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Denis. can you provide an example code? Can you give the iterator a start point that is where you left off ? A bit confused how would you serve large data set to web clients without breaking the server...

Comment: @Gadi, you can find all information on scan queries here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-scan-queries You can treat `QueryCursor` as an `Iterable`. `ScanQuery` cannot be told where to start, but you can keep an iterator without closing it until it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks, @Denis, that will make a very messy session handling I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @Gadi you can always create a helper method to paginate your results, remove mess from main code flow.